# IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Al correr este código en jupyter:

```
def plot_feature_importances_cancer(model):
n_features = cancer.data.shape[1]
plt.barh(range(n_features), model.feature_importances_, align='center')
plt.yticks(np.arange(n_features), cancer.feature_names)
plt.xlabel("Feature importance")
plt.ylabel("Feature")
plot_feature_importances_cancer(tree)
```

aparece este error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-19-a558f64f826a>", line 2
>     n_features = cancer.data.shape[1]
>              ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block
> ```

Estoy trabajando en Windows 7

Comment: Jhony bienvenido a [es.so]. El error es muy claro, se espera un nivel de identación en esa línea y no está. En Python los bloques de código se delimitan usando identación. Para poder ayudarte es imprescindible que peges el código tal y como lo tienes, **manteniendo el formato exactamente como está en tu NoteBook**. Por favor, edita la pregunta, copia tu código, lo seleccionas y pulsa el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl + k para que quede formateado como código y se mantenga la identación tal y como la tienes tu. Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

El error es muy claro, se espera que exista un bloque de identación entre la segunda línea y la primera. Python identifica los bloques de código mediante los diferentes niveles de identación y no mediante simbología específica como llaves o palabras reservadas (`Begin`, `End`, etc) como supongo que ya sabrás.

Como ya te comenté es importante que agreges el código correctamente formateado porque un error de identación puede deberse a varios motivos, entre ellos mezclar tabulaciones y espacios. Esto solo es posible detectarlo si copias y formateas el código tal y como lo tienes tu en tu editor.

Dado que tu código es simple y siguiendo las recomendaciones de **PEP-8** sobre identación (uso de 4 espacios entre niveles), tu código debería ser (a falta de mejor contexto):

```
def plot_feature_importances_cancer(model):
    n_features = cancer.data.shape[1]
    plt.barh(range(n_features), model.feature_importances_, align='center')
    plt.yticks(np.arange(n_features), cancer.feature_names)
    plt.xlabel("Feature importance")
    plt.ylabel("Feature")

plot_feature_importances_cancer(tree)
```